# QGIS does not launch after plugin and python loading

Tags: qgis, windows

I have a big problem with lauching QGIS. I have been using QGIS in the past, but now I can't launch it. I tried re-install, but it doesn't help. I tried install different versions of QGIS (1.7, 1.8, 2), but in every version process is finished after loading plugins and python...

When I want to launch QGIS via command line... QGIS is open, and after loading plugins/python nothing happens... Windows is closed, processed is finished.

In install post reports there aren't any errors.

Do you have any idea why?

Comment: Have you tried launching QGIS via the command line **without loading the plugins**? Try `qgis --noplugins` and see if QGIS loads.

Comment: @adamsss. I assume that you've already fixed it, but just in case I had the same problem after setting up an independent python path to the environment variables on windows. It messed up both ARC & Q gis. I fixed by deleting python completely, removing it manually from PATH, and PY_HOME, and reinstalling, qgis.